# Problema con aplicaciòn web con Maven y Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, maven, intellij-idea

Bueno, tengo mi aplicación web que tiene el backend en `Java` y que trabaja con `Hibernate`, `Jackson` (para el parseo de json a objetos y viceversa) y `Jersey` para la API Rest. El problema es que cuando le pongo "start" al servidor (`Tomcat 8`) tengo una `java.lang.NoDefClassFoundException` diciendo que no encuentra la clase `Persistence`, pero lo raro es que tengo la dependencia de `Hibernate 5.2.7` (que supuestamente trae la `jpa-api` con su propia implementación de la clase `Persistence`) y no se porque me sigue saliendo ese error. Me fijo en las dependencias de Maven y el paquete `javax.persistence` está ahí, y también la clase `Persistence`, por lo tanto no se que es lo que puede estar pasando. Ya van 2 días enteros que le voy dedicando a la búsqueda de la solución pero no la he podido encontrar.

Cualquier ayuda es muy agradecida. Les dejo el `pom.xml` y el árbol de archivos que tengo.

PD: Estoy trabajando con IntelliJ Idea, no se si eso afectará en algo (por ej. que haya que configurar algo que yo no sepa o este pasando por alto).

`pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MissingDog</groupId>
  <artifactId>MissingDog</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MissingDog Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PostgreSQL Driver -->
      <!-- postgresql -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.1212</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End PostgreSQL Driver -->

    <!-- Hibernate -->
      <!-- hibernate-core -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
      </dependency>
    <!-- End Hibernate -->

    <!-- Jackson -->
      <!-- jackson-annotations -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jackson-core -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jackson-databind -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Jackson -->

    <!-- Jersey -->
      <!-- javax.ws.rs-api -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jersey-client -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
          <version>2.25</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jersey-container-servlet -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>2.25</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jersey-server -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
          <version>2.25</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
    <!-- End Jersey -->

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>MissingDog</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

arbol de dependencias:
[image: dependencias]

EDIT: Añado la stack trace del error:

```
28-Jan-2017 13:25:49.478 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(7)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase controllers.MissingDogListener
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at util.JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory(JPAUtil.java:15)
    at controllers.MissingDogListener.contextInitialized(MissingDogListener.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 47 more

28-Jan-2017 13:25:49.482 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(7)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Excepción enviando evento de contexto destruído a instancia de escuchador de clase controllers.MissingDogListener
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
    at util.JPAUtil.shutdown(JPAUtil.java:30)
    at controllers.MissingDogListener.contextDestroyed(MissingDogListener.java:18)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4889)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5526)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 48 more
```

EDIT 2:
`JPAUtil.java`:

```
package util;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class JPAUtil {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public static void buildEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName) {

        if(emf == null) {
            try {
                emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if(emf == null)
            return null;
        else
            return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if(emf.isOpen()) emf.close();
    }
}
```

`persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MissingDog">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/missingDog"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>

            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

`MascotaDAO`:

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import model.Mascota;
import util.JPAUtil;

public class MascotaDAO {

    public void guardar(Mascota entity) throws Exception {
        //Creo el pool de conexiones si es que no esta creado
//      try {
//          JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory("MissingDog");
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
//      }

        //Tomo una conexion y creo una transaccion
        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction txn = em.getTransaction();

        //Guardo la mascota
        try {
            txn.begin();
            em.persist(entity);
            txn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(txn.isActive())
                txn.rollback();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public void eliminar(Integer id) throws Exception {
        //Creo el pool de conexiones si es que no esta creado
//      try {
//          JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory("MissingDog");
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
//      }

        //Tomo una conexion y busco todas las mascotas cargadas en la base de datos
        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<Mascota> query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Mascota m WHERE m.id=" + id, Mascota.class);
        Mascota mascota = query.getSingleResult();

        //Elimino la mascota
        EntityTransaction txn = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            txn.begin();
            em.remove(mascota);
            txn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(txn.isActive())
                txn.rollback();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public void actualizar(Mascota entity) throws Exception {
        //Creo el pool de conexiones si es que no esta creado
//      try {
//          JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory("MissingDog");
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
//      }

        //Tomo una conexion y creo una transaccion
        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction txn = em.getTransaction();
        Mascota mascota = null;

        try {
            txn.begin();
            //Busco la mascota para comprobar que este en la base de datos
            mascota = em.find(Mascota.class, entity);
            //La actualizo si es que est�
            if(mascota != null) {
                em.merge(mascota);
                txn.commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(txn.isActive() && mascota != null)
                txn.rollback();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public List<Mascota> buscarPorRaza(String raza) {
        //Creo el pool de conexiones si es que no esta creado
//      try {
//          JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory("MissingDog");
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
//      }

        //Tomo una conexion y busco todas las mascotas con esa raza
        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<Mascota> query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Mascota m WHERE m.raza=" + raza, Mascota.class);
        List<Mascota> mascotas = query.getResultList();

        return mascotas;
    }

    public List<Mascota> listarMascotas() {
        //Creo el pool de conexiones si es que no esta creado
//      try {
//          JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory("MissingDog");
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
//      }

        //Tomo una conexion y busco todas las mascotas
        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<Mascota> query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Mascota m", Mascota.class);
        List<Mascota> mascotas = query.getResultList();

        return mascotas;
    }
}
```

Comment: Añade la traza de error completa, por favor.

Comment: Añade el código de tu clase JPAUtil.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta la dependencia

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Tambien puedes cambiar la última por la declaración de eclipse

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: me sale otro error si agrego esa dependencia "method createQuery in interface javax.persistence.EntityManager cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: java.lang.String
[ERROR] found: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<model.Mascota>
[ERROR] reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]". Eso sale cuando trato de hacer un 'clean install' desde maven

Comment: Tienes un error en la linea donde usas createQuery estas pasando como query un objeto cuando deberia ser un string con JPQL, la sintaxis correcta seria algo como `Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Mascota m");` o  `TypedQuery<Mascota> q2 =
      em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Mascota m", Mascota.class);`

Comment: TypedQuery<Mascota> query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Mascota m WHERE m.id=" + id, Mascota.class); esta es la linea donde me genera el error... lo raro es que lo estoy pasando como String, pero me sigue diciendo que no encuentra esa version del metodo con 2 parametros. Ahi agregue la clase que hace la llamada al metodo createQuery

Comment: Tienes razon... la dependencia debe ser para JPA 2.0, actualice mi respuesta con esa dependencia

Comment: si cambio la dependencia y saco la de javax.persistence me sale el error anterior, que no encuentra la clase Persistence. Por alguna razon que no puedo ver cual es no esta usando el paquete de hibernate

Comment: alguna idea @DanyelDarkcloud???

Comment: El último jar ya tiene la declaración javax.persistence.Persistence.... el war generado por maven tiene en la carpeta `WEB-INF/lib/` el archivo `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.jar`?

Comment: como me fijo los archivos que tiene un war?? si voy a la carpeta "target > MissingDog > WEB-INF > lib" del proyecto si esta ese jar, pero no se si esa es la carpeta generada por Maven

Comment: Un WAR esta construido sobre la especificación del formato ZIP, por lo que cambiar el nombre del archivo a .ZIP hace posible abrirlo con el explorador de windows.  Y si.. esa es la carpeta generada por maven. En la respuesta añadi otra librería que también provee la especificación JPA 2.0. Prueba también con ella. Así mismo recuerda hacer un clean completo en tu proyecto y reiniciar el servidor para evitar problemas

Comment: le cambie la extension al .war y vi que no estaba añadiendo las librerias a la carpeta "WEB-INF > lib". ¿Porque puede ser esto?

Comment: creo que encontre la solucion... el artefacto que estaba desplegando en el servidor, por alguna razon, no tenia la carpeta lib dentro de web-inf, por lo tanto no copiaba las librerias... por lo tanto cree uno nuevo, le asigne las librerias y ahora anda... por lo menos despliega el war... pero me sale Error 404 cuando trato de acceder a la pagina

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52814/discussion-between-danyel-darkcloud-and-augusto-herbel).

Answer (score 0):

Estás trabajando con EntityManagers, con lo que entiendo necesitas cambiar tu dependencia

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

por

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Por otro lado, necesitarás un fichero META-INF/persistence.xml, que no sé si habrás creado. Para más información, consulta la documentación de hibernate + JPA [aquí](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial_jpa).

Comment: me sigue saliendo el mismo error... si tengo el persistence.xml creado y configurado

Comment: alguna idea de porque puede seguir pasando incluso cambiando las dependencias?? @pablo

Comment: Actualiza el pom.xml y añade el persistence.xml también.

Comment: añadido el persistence y actualizado el pom.xml