# ocultar mensajes de hibenate o solucionarlos

Tags: java, hibernate

Buenas me salen estos mensaje en Hibernate al hacer una consulta

```
ene 19, 2020 7:34:47 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
ene 19, 2020 7:34:47 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
ene 19, 2020 7:34:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
ene 19, 2020 7:34:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
ene 19, 2020 7:34:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root}
ene 19, 2020 7:34:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
ene 19, 2020 7:34:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
ene 19, 2020 7:34:49 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
ene 19, 2020 7:34:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

puesto que la consulta si me la realiza correctamente pues una de 2 o lo solucionamos o lo oculto como lo hago?

He probado poniendo

```
Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Pero no me sirve si uso este tipo de consulta

```
 SessionFactory instancia = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session sesion = instancia.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = sesion.beginTransaction();
        List q = sesion.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM City",City.class ).getResultList();
        Iterator<City> it = q.iterator();
        City e;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            e = it.next();
            System.out.println(e.getCity() + " " + e.getCountry());
        }

        sesion.close();
    }
```

si uso Query en vez de native query si rula pero esta obsoleta

Comment: Como configuraste hibernate,  ¿desde una clase o desde un archivo XML? ¿Requieres que en pantalla no te aparezcan los niveles de error WARN e INFO?

Comment: Configue con un xml hibernate.cfg.xml, claro la idea es que solo me de la consulta la info no la quiero para nada, lo ideal es que solo me aparezca si ocurre algo grave

Comment: Necesitas configurar el archivo log4j.properties, Acá un ejemplo: https://mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-log4j-in-hibernate-project/ . La clave es la linea **log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO** que es dónde indicas a partir de que nivel de trazas quieres ver. Si no quieres ver los niveles **INFO** y **WARN** debes cambiar **INFO** por **ERROR**.

Comment: no tengo tal archivo

Comment: Para el warn puedes agregar la configuración para que te haga un pool de tamaño personalizado como en https://stackoverflow.com/a/75713514/6999690

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con aplicaciòn web con Maven y Hibernate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/problema-con-aplicaci%c3%b2n-web-con-maven-y-hibernate)

Comment: Matías te menciona como configurarlo si tieness log4j, yo hallé esto en un foro https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2402968 por lo que te recomiendo especifiques si usas alguna librería de logs